# Canvas Deburring Algorithm

Tags: image-processing, canvas, edge-detection

I've got an little canvas tool I've built that cut up images into little pieces to move around, and it's working great except the resulting pieces often have little spikes left on them that I would like to remove, but I can't figure out a good algorithm for detecting and removing them. I'm not sure if an edge smoothing algorithm would work, the ones I've checked out seem like they would interpret the spikes as part of the shape. Here's an example of what one of these image pieces might look like.

[image]

Can anyone recommend anything that might get rid of the spikes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try morphology filter [opening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology), if the structure of main figure is rather simple.
Opening is erosion + dilation, so it removes small and thin elements, then restores (of course, with some artefacts) initial form of big objects.

Comment: Interesting, that's a route I would have never thought to take. I'll try it out.

Comment: Also, in case anyone else is interested in this topic, this http://www.aishack.in/2010/07/mathematical-morphology/ is a really good, simple explanation of what it is and how to do it.

Comment: That is very far from being a good explanation of erosion/dilation. The illustrations for the erosion operation are so wrong that I can't understand how someone would consider that a good explanation in any way. Soille's book, Morphological Image Analysis: Principles and Applications, is a decent and easy to follow text on Mathematical Morphology. For a theoretic reading into MM, consider Serra's book for a starting point.